# Subset a new dataframe with binary columns

Tags: r, binary, multiple-columns

I would like to identify binary columns in a data.frame. And make a new df on based that condition.

For example, this table

```
my.table <-read.table(text="a,b,c
0,2,0
0.25,1,1
1,0,0", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can keep columns that have only 0 and 1 value.

```
Filter(function(x) all(x %in% c(0, 1)), my.table)

#  c
#1 0
#2 1
#3 0
```

---

Few other variations to do the same thing :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#2
my.table[colSums(my.table == 0 | my.table  == 1) == nrow(my.table)]
#3
my.table %>% select(where(~all(. %in% c(0, 1))))
#4
keep(my.table, ~all(. %in% c(0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
my.table[colSums(sapply(my.table, `%in%`, c(0, 1))) == nrow(my.table)]
#  c
#1 0
#2 1
#3 0
```